# Is there a way to use the everyone role in discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, discord.js

I'm trying to make my lock and mute command work with a per server settings command I recently made with mongodb. I want it to be where it gets the member role from the database (roles.cache.get(guildProfile.memberRoleID)) and then if there isn't one set it locks the channel for the everyone role. Idk what the everyone role in discord.js is though. Also when I try to pass in the member role from the db it says that its an invalid code, even with one set in the db

This is the role variable (using let): `let role = message.guild.roles.cache.get(guildProfile.memberRoleID)`

This is the if statement if there's no role: `if (!role) role = (everyone would go here)`

This is the actual locking of the channel: `await lockChannel.updateOverwrite(role, { SEND_MESSAGES: false }).catch(err => console.log(err));`

Comment: The guild profile thing now works. I tried message.guild.defaultRole (I saw in a similar question someone suggested it) but it gives an error:  [INVALID_TYPE]: Supplied parameter is not a User nor a Role. I also added .toString on the end (as the other question suggested that too) but it says its undefined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [RoleManager.everyone](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/RoleManager?scrollTo=everyone)

```js
if(!role) role = message.guild.roles.everyone
```

Comment: +upvote since your answer is better and more efficient than mine.

Answer (score 2):

This is how you can get the everyone role.

```js
const everyone = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "@everyone");
```